# how use prettier Ignore block for JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, prettier

How can I make prettier ignore some blocks in JSX? For Example:

```js
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/"           element={<Home      />} />
          <Route path="/aboutUs"    element={<AboutUs   />} />
          <Route path="/contact"    element={<Contact   />} />
          <Route path="/infos"      element={<Infos     />} />
          <Route path="/request"    element={<Request   />} />
          <Route path="/impressum"  element={<Impressum />} />
          <Route path="/whatsabu"   element={<WhatsaBu  />} />
          <Route path="/test"       element={<Test      />} />
          <Route path="/compare"    element={<Compare   />} />
          <Route path="/partner"    element={<Partner   />} />
          <Route path="/concept"    element={<Concept   />} />
          <Route path="/blog"       element={<Blog      />} />
          <Route path="/privacy"    element={<Privacy   />} />
          <Route path="/bonus"      element={<Bonus     />} />
        </Routes>
```

only solution I could find is: `{/* prettier-ignore */}` but I had to write it on every second line.  `{/* prettier-ignore-start */}` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `//prettier-ignore` above the block.

```js
        //prettier-ignore
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/"           element={<Home      />} />
          <Route path="/aboutUs"    element={<AboutUs   />} />
          <Route path="/contact"    element={<Contact   />} />
          <Route path="/infos"      element={<Infos     />} />
          <Route path="/request"    element={<Request   />} />
          <Route path="/impressum"  element={<Impressum />} />
          <Route path="/whatsabu"   element={<WhatsaBu  />} />
          <Route path="/test"       element={<Test      />} />
          <Route path="/compare"    element={<Compare   />} />
          <Route path="/partner"    element={<Partner   />} />
          <Route path="/concept"    element={<Concept   />} />
          <Route path="/blog"       element={<Blog      />} />
          <Route path="/privacy"    element={<Privacy   />} />
          <Route path="/bonus"      element={<Bonus     />} />
        </Routes>
```

Comment: doesn't work, because it's a other language https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to place the comment in between blocks of JSX?

Comment: I want to do like: "ignore command start " "Routes...Routes" "irgnore command end". Not,  "ignore cmd , route, ignore cmd, route .... this works but dont worth it

Answer (score 0):

for jsx, use `{/* prettier-ignore */}` (or `{           // prettier-ignore           <>`)

ex:

```
export default function HomePage() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>HomePage</Text>
      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}>
        {/* prettier-ignore */}
        <>
          <Link style={[styles.link, styles.largefontsize]} href="/HomeDetailsPage">HomeDetailsPage</Link>
          <Link style={[styles.link, styles.largefontsize]} href="/Home2ndSameLvPage">Home2ndSameLvPage</Link>
          <Link style={[styles.link, styles.largefontsize]} href="/about/">AboutPage</Link>
          <Link style={[styles.link, styles.largefontsize]} href="/aboutNamed/AboutNamedPage">AboutNamedPage</Link>
          <Link style={[styles.link, styles.largefontsize]} href="/aboutRedirect/">AboutRedirectPage</Link>
          <Link style={[styles.link, styles.largefontsize]} href="/users/1">/users/1</Link>
          <Link style={[styles.link, styles.mediumfontsize]} numberOfLines={1} href="/users/2?sortActivity=desc&time=yesterday">/users/2?sortActivity=desc&time=yesterday</Link>
          <Link style={[styles.link, styles.mediumfontsize]} numberOfLines={1} href="/dataFolder/kaggle/c/lsm?sortDate=desc&time=yesterday">/dataFolder/kaggle/c/lsm?sortDate=desc&time=yesterday</Link>
        </>
        <Link
          style={[styles.link, styles.mediumfontsize]}
          numberOfLines={1}
          href={{
            pathname: '/dataFolder/kaggle/c/lsm',
            params: { sortDate: 'desc', time: 'yesterday' },
          }}
          push
        >
          /dataFolder/kaggle/c/lsm?sortDate=desc&time=yesterday
        </Link>
        <Pressable
          onPress={() => {
            // router.push('/dataFolder/kaggle/c/lsm?sortDate=desc&time=yesterday');
            router.push({
              pathname: '/dataFolder/kaggle/c/lsm',
              params: { sortDate: 'desc', time: 'yesterday' },
            });
          }}
        >
          {/* prettier-ignore */}
          <Text style={[styles.link, styles.mediumfontsize]} numberOfLines={1}>/dataFolder/kaggle/c/lsm?sortDate=desc&time=yesterday</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

```
        {
          // prettier-ignore
          <>
            <Link style={[styles.link, styles.largefontsize]} href="/HomeDetailsPage">HomeDetailsPage</Link>
            <Link style={[styles.link, styles.largefontsize]} href="/Home2ndSameLvPage">Home2ndSameLvPage</Link>
            <Link style={[styles.link, styles.largefontsize]} href="/about/">AboutPage</Link>
            <Link style={[styles.link, styles.largefontsize]} href="/aboutNamed/AboutNamedPage">AboutNamedPage</Link>
            <Link style={[styles.link, styles.largefontsize]} href="/aboutRedirect/">AboutRedirectPage</Link>
            <Link style={[styles.link, styles.largefontsize]} href="/users/1">/users/1</Link>
            <Link style={[styles.link, styles.mediumfontsize]} numberOfLines={1} href="/users/2?sortActivity=desc&time=yesterday">/users/2?sortActivity=desc&time=yesterday</Link>
            <Link style={[styles.link, styles.mediumfontsize]} numberOfLines={1} href="/dataFolder/kaggle/c/lsm?sortDate=desc&time=yesterday">/dataFolder/kaggle/c/lsm?sortDate=desc&time=yesterday</Link>
          </>
        }
```

- (dont add any redundant characters)
- (wish there was doc for this... once tried, but never found out until now)
- (`// prettier-ignore` can only be at start of a jsx block; 
  though it can be at end if its single line; 
  ((you may play with it to try out more ways yourself, but I tried and dont see other ways)))
- (Idk why OP said it doesnt work, maybe OP needed to try to utilize `<></>`)